# Getting reading 'largeUnit' while, drag and drop of the Event

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

We have downloaded the free version of fullCalendar and uploaded as a static resource in the salesforce Org. While implementing drag and drop functionality, we are facing some issue - getting

> "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'largeUnit')"

error in the Salesforce .

```
dragScroll: true,
droppable: true,
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        console.log("event drop+", event.Id);
        if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
          revertFunc();
        } else {
          var eventid = event.id;
          var eventdate = event.start.format();
          self.editEvent(component, eventid, eventdate);
          console.log("eventid+", eventid);
          console.log("eventdate+", eventdate);
        }
}
```

Can you please help me, how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: The error message shows fullcalendar-3.0.0 as your version, at lest according to the folder name. But you've tagged this post with fullcalendar-4, which is quite different. Which version are you actually using? 3.0.0 is both very old, and the first in the 3.x series, so likely to have a lot of bugs. But if you only just downloaded this, choosing either 3.x or 4.x makes very little sense - the latest released version is 5.11.3 which has improved performance, lots of new features, and lots of bug fixes. I'd suggest trying the latest version and see if that helps your issue.

Comment: (Note that if you do that, you'll need to amend the eventDrop code slightly - check the latest docs to get started... https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc ).

Comment: We are using fullcalendar- 3 version

Comment: Why? Like I said, this version is really old and probably has bugs